# Nuxt JS / Github Pages - aborted: problem pushing local branch to remote

Tags: nuxt.js, github-pages

I'm fairly new to Nuxt js. I've asked a couple of times on the nuxt discord with no response and hoping someone might be able to help.

I'm trying to deploy my nuxt project to Github to use with Github Pages. If I do the following process on my personal account, it seems to work. However, now that i'm signed into my organisation account to create a website for a project, i receive the error:

`aborted: problem pushing local branch to remote`

**Steps Taken**

1. Fresh new project created following these exact steps: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/installation
2. Deployed project following these exact steps: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/github-pages/

On my personal account, when running the `npm run deploy` script ( `"deploy": "push-dir --dir=dist --branch=gh-pages --cleanup"`), a new temporary branch is created and then saved to a freshly created `gh-pages` branch which i can then use for my live site.

However, when running the exact same script on a new project, with the only difference being the account i'm signed into the script fails with:

`aborted: problem pushing local branch to remote`

If anyone has any idea what could be causing this, it would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and it was because I forgot to set these 2 git configs:

```
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

The error message comes from the push-dir package [here](https://github.com/L33T-KR3W/push-dir/blob/a708b3c95a4fd4698ee0a4dc91090ca2796ae174/index.js#L101) so try running the full command and see if you get the same issue first `git --work-tree dist commit -m "test"`

Comment: I bumped into this error too when I was building my Nuxt.js project in a Gitlab pipeline. What I did is add --verbose to push-dir and it did tell me what was wrong. The one posted by @pspkazy is exactly my issue. Therefore, I give you my +1.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your remote git branches with `git remote -v`,
should give something like

```
origin  git@github.com:name/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:name/repo.git (push)
```

Also, double check that the remote branch is not ahead of your local changes, if it's the case, `pull` the remote changes to your local code.

Lastly, you maybe just don't have the rights to push there or create new branches ? Maybe you need some other SSH keys for the organization ? Can you push a regular branch there ?

Comment: Thanks for the response @kissue. `remote -v` displays the correct origins. Re: pull - all changes are in sync. I have the ability to create new branches and push to them via Github desktop or on the web. It's just whenever I run that script that things fall apart. It gets as far as creating a temporary `gh-pages-283872` repo (random number) and then stops with an error. Ordinarily this should create a temp repo and then create a clean `gh-pages` repo to sync to.